# File found but scanner doesn't read

Tags: java, text-files, java.util.scanner

I have a problem with my scanner reading a .txt file.
I've done as in all my other projects (as far as I can see) but it doesn't read it.
The .txt contains information which is split using \t.

```
public class Bank_Test {

ArrayList<Bank> banks = new ArrayList<>();

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Bank_Test bank_test = new Bank_Test();

    bank_test.fillArray();

}

private void fillArray() {

    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("123.txt"))) {

        String[] tokens;
        String line;

        Bank bank;

        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scan.nextLine();
            tokens = line.split("\t");

            bank = new Bank(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2]);

            banks.add(bank);
        }

        System.out.println(banks);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Where am I wrong in reading the file?

Comment: "It doesn't read it" doesn't tell us what is happening. Do you get an exception? Do you simply not get the results you're expecting? What results do you get? By the way `new Integer` is deprecated, `Integer.valueOf` is the way to get an `Integer`, but since you want an `int` you should just use `Integer.parseInt`.

Comment: Also, you declare `banks` as both a field of the class, and a local variable in `main` which shadows (hides) the declaration of the field. The declaration of the field is correct, but the declaration of the local var leaves off the `<>` "diamond syntax" and so is using a raw type. These things aren't causing you any trouble -- yet. But they are best avoided. For now, I would simply remove the field and add the `<>` to the instantiation of the local var.

Comment: @DavidConrad It doesn't give me FileNotFound from the catch therefor I expect it to have found the file. The array I'm trying to put it into is still at 0 size after runtime.

Comment: i tested your code and it runs correctly. are you sure the file has contents inside it

Comment: @user3170251 I'm sure. The txt file has 200 or so entries but Java doesn't seem to load them in via the scanner.

I'm not getting any exceptions or anything like that and Java terminates execution with the ArrayList at a size of 0.

Comment: Maybe you're using a different text file that's empty? Check if the name of the text file matches the name in your program. Other than that, I have no idea what could be causing it

Comment: @user3170251 I've copied the name from the file directly into the code to avoid any mismatches and type-o's and the txt is the only one in the root folder of the system.
The wierdest thing is that I've done this in other programs and looked for any difference in the other times i've done this but i can't seem to find the issue.

Comment: I've not found out that it does find the file BUT it sees it a empty. how can this be?

Comment: What is the output of the program? This code could easily get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException or NumberFormatException, but if it reads a file with plenty of entries it should produce some output. Also, please see [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: @DavidConrad I've made the program print out the ArrayList when it's done reading the file. This is an empty array. No exceptions pr any errors are outputted in the console.
As I see it; the program sees the file but it cant read it i.e. sees the file as empty. I've copied the method form my other projects to this one and it does the same eventhough the method works in the other project.

Comment: No, you also made the program print `System.out.println("bank = " + bank);` for each one it reads. Do you see that in the output? You could also make the program print each line as it reads it. `System.out.println(line);` What happens if you add that? I've run your program on my computer with a sample file, and it works fine, although there are a few compiler warnings you should fix.

Comment: Is the code you're running identical to what you've posted? Because there are two different ArrayLists in your program; one field, one local var shadowing the field. You add the banks to one of them; are you sure you're not printing out the size of the other one (the field) to which you never add anything?

Comment: @DavidConrad I've uploaded my new code to the question. As of now It doesn't reach the while-loop. This makes me think that it as found the file but sees it as empty. I've also changed the name of the file to see if it would give any error but still the same. the filename does still match the code though

Comment: As a side-note, using the scanner to retrieve a whole line then splitting this line over `\t` is kinda wasteful : you could instead set the scanner delimiter's to `[\n\t]` and just loop over `scanner.next()`. ([illustration](https://ideone.com/DKfYE3))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the source of the issue.

My .txt file was saved as a txt with ANSI coding via Windows. Changing it to UTF-8 fixes  the problem.

Hope it helps others in the future.